# How do i create an application token for my Azure application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, api, azure-devops

So i'm trying to get a token from the "OAuth 2.0 token endpoint (v2)" endpoint that exists in my Azure app. That's it.

```
[HttpGet("GetApplicationToken")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetApplicationToken()
{
      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
      var url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/680ea9b1-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token";

      var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
      {
          {"client_id", "41d391ef-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" },
          {"scope", "api://41d391ef-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/access_as_user" },
          {"client_secret", "PXa8Q~xx" },
          {"grant_type", "client_credentials" }
      };
      var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);

      var response = await client.PostAsync(url, encodedContent);

      if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
          var responseStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
          return Ok(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(responseStr));
      }

      return StatusCode(500);
```

The output i get is:

```
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6.1","title":"An error occurred while processing your request.","status":500,"traceId":"00-d0da4fd71ec21cb0f8b364e3853bda37-ed1dcd82609eef73-00"}
```

I want this to return an application token that my api can use, but i don't have a clue what the issue might be.
Thanks!

Comment: Your code doesn't replace the `{tenantId}` in the uri with the actual tenant id.

Comment: @NotFound In the actual code it's the id. I wrote `{tenantId}` to censor it but i should have done it in the same style as the clientId, will edit

Answer (score 0):

The scope parameter should be "api://41d391ef-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/.default" when using client credentials flow.
This is because you can only use statically defined permissions in the app registration, unlike authentication flows where a user is involved which can use scopes dynamically.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret.

Quote from documentation about the scope parameter:

> The value passed for the scope parameter in this request should be the resource identifier (application ID URI) of the resource you want, affixed with the .default suffix.

(it can be the client/application ID too in addition to the app ID URI though)

Also, it would be a good idea to read the response content regardless of success status code or not, so you can check the error returned.
Additionally, it would be easier to use [MSAL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client) for this purpose instead of calling the APIs manually.

Comment: This does not solve the problem sadly. Even though the scope was clearly wrong. I guess theres some other problem too